# how to export project to jar package

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

I want to share my Android Studio 2.1 project. In order to do this, I want to export it as a jar package and then give it to my customer to use it.
How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to export a library as a jar or a whole app? Projects are typically packaged as APKs, and Android libs as AARs

Answer (score 0):

I think, you might want to share your project on [github.com](http://github.com)  . it's not that hard to use and you can upload updates fom your android studio!

Another possible way is just to copy your whole project/module folder. and zip it. or whatever.

If you still want to create .jar:

this works with modules. I think it might also work in your case. To your build.gradle add this code:

```
//replace mylibrary with your module name
task deleteJar(type:Delete){
    delete 'libs/mylibrary.jar'
}

task createJar(type: Copy){
from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('libs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar','mylibrary.jar')

}
createJar.dependsOn(deleteJar, build)
```

sync your project. then click on this:[image: click on this]
now, you've created a jar in the /libs folder of your project.